# What is the max length of a string in ".bat" or ".cmd"?

Tags: batch-file

***I've just met a problem to display a very long text in an batch file just for fun.
Is it any limitation that the string is too long to exceed the memory or other restriction?***

```
REM Just an demo that I will use
echo "........................very long text............................................"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2047 characters in 32-bit operating system.
8191 characters in 64-bit operating system.
More information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473

Comment: This is wrong. It is 8191 chars. from Windows XP onward, don't matter if it is 32 or 64 bits...